# Remove overly specific tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

[How can an SQL query return data from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12475850/238886) is tagged [php](/questions/tagged/php), but it's really all about SQL in general, and MYSQL in particular.  None of the answers mention PHP or include any PHP code.

I believe the author tagged it with PHP because:

> Note: I am writing this as I would like to be able to link to a well
>   written guide on the numerous questions that I constantly come across
>   in the PHP queue, so I can link to this for further detail when I post
>   an answer.

I would otherwise remove the PHP tag, but that note gives me pause.  Should the PHP tag be removed from this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it doesn't need the [php](/questions/tagged/php) tag if it doesn't relate to it *at all*. If someone's going to link to that question or close as duplicate, they should explain that the behaviour is unrelated to PHP. Anyway, if that's the case then usually it's not an *exact* duplicate, though I understand that it's rarely used only for exact duplicates.